# How do I insert a string that contains an '?

Tags: sql

I'm looking to include a value into my datatable but a string value includes a '. How do I add it to my table?

```
insert into mytable
(ISO_COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY, REGION)
values ('CI', 'COTE D'IVOIRE','EMEAR')
```

As you can see I will get an error if I input this like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the query

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ISO_COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY, REGION)
VALUES ('CI', 'COTE D''IVOIRE', 'EMEAR');
```